# jQuery to JavaScript Translation for Append(), One()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What would be the JavaScript Equivalent to these jQuery functions. This is what I have but for some reason I cannot find the equivalent to the last function.

```
My Code  
    game[0].appendChild(thisBox);

    setTimeout(function () {
        thisBox.classList.add("move");
    }, random(0, 3000));

    // thisBox.one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
    //     function (event) {
    //         $(this).remove();
    //     });
```

```
Code I am trying to translate
//insert gift element
  $(".game").append(thisBox);

  //random start for animation
  setTimeout(function(){
    thisBox.addClass("move");
  }, random(0, 5000) );

  thisBox.one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend",
     function(event) {
    $(this).remove();
  });
```

Comment: There is no built in equivalent. From just looking at `.one` I suspect it involves a string that is split and is looped over per event name. Then `addEventListener` is used in combination with the `{once: true}` as the options parameter.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Answer (score 0):

A translation to vanilla JS would be to add an event listener for each of those event types, with `{ once: true }` so that each event callback only runs once, maximum:

```
'webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend'
  .split(' ')
  .forEach((eventName) => {
    thisBox.addEventListener(eventName, () => thisBox.remove(), { once: true });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the form of a function it would look like this. The input would be different for the added third parameter because of the element that you want to pass to bind the event listener to.

```
/**
 * @param {string} eventNames
 * @param {EventTarget} eventTarget
 * @param {function} callback
 */
function one(eventNames, eventTarget, callback) {
  if ('string' !== typeof eventNames || 
    !(eventTarget instanceof EventTarget) || 
    'function' !== typeof callback
  ) return;
  const splitEventNames = eventNames.split(' ');
  for (const eventName of splitEventNames) {
    eventTarget.addEventListener(eventName, callback, { once: true });
  }
}
```

Usage would be like this, with the first argument being the events to listen to, the second argument the element to add the event listener on, and the third argument the callback function to call when the event fires.

```
one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', thisBox, function(event) {
  this.remove();
});
```